# Use Redux-Toolkit mutation with createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to create a login API call from the auth slice. I use both Redux-Toolkit (RTK) and RTK Query in the project. I want to use `fetchBaseQuery` in the API call. I have predefined `baseQuery`.

```js
export const baseQuery = retry(fetchBaseQuery({
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY) || '';
    const uid = getLocal(UID_KEY);
    if (accessToken) {
      headers.set('Authorization', accessToken);
      headers.set(UID_KEY, uid);
    }
    return headers;
  },
}), { maxRetries: 3 });
```

My expectation is to use a RTK mutation in the `authSlice`. I have tried like this, but it is not working.

```js
export const loginAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/login',
  async (credentials: LoginValuesType, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      // How to call the mutation here?
      // const response = await userApi.useLoginMutation(credentials)
    
      if (response?.data?.code === 0) {
        localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, response.data?.data?.token);
        setLocal('uid', response.data?.data?.uid);
        return response.data;
      } else if (response?.data?.code === 1) {
        thunkAPI.dispatch(showError(response?.data?.msg))
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({msg: response?.data?.msg})
      }
    } catch (e) {
      thunkAPI.dispatch(showError('An error occurred'))
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({msg: "An error occurred"})
    }
  }
)
```

If this way is impossible please suggest me a good way to create this backend connection.

This is the RTK mutation I have implemented. We can remove it if it is not necessary.

```js
export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'userApi',
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({       
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (args) => {
        return {
          url: '/api/v1/sign_in',
          method: 'POST',
          body: args,
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useLoginMutation
} = userApi;
```

Comment: RTK Query already uses a thunk internally, there is usually no good reason to wrap another thunk around it like you are doing - add some `extraReducers` for `fulfilled` or `rejected` actions instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [initiate](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#initiate) an endpoint directly. Example:

```js
export const loginAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/login',
  async (credentials: LoginValuesType, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await thunkApi.dispatch(
        userApi.endpoints.login.initiate(credentials);
      );
    
      if (data.code === 0) {
        localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, data.data?.token);
        setLocal('uid', data.data?.uid);
        return data;
      } else if (data.code === 1) {
        const { msg } = data;
        thunkApi.dispatch(showError(msg));
        return thunkApi.rejectWithValue({ msg });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      thunkApi.dispatch(showError('An error occurred'));
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue({ msg: "An error occurred" });
    }
  }
);
```